# How to select what tag should be "primary" for the question?

Tags: support, tags

When a user visits a question, the HTML page header contains the whole title of a question, prepended by a tag, one of those the question bears. How to determine which tag is displayed there, and how to choose a tag that an asker desires to be displayed in the page header?

This is also frustrating when you open multiple tabs of SO, searching for a problem regarding one language, then accidentally close the one you really needed because it displays some tag that's relevant to the question but is completely irrelevant to the problem you face. Is there a criteria which tag should be displayed if there are multiple tags assigned to the question? So far I am unable to guess which criteria is applied to select a tag that's displayed. For example, [this question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428196/) on ruSO displays `cmd` tag, which is not most popular among selected tags (89 question against 540 for `xml`), is not the first and not the last tag listed under the question.